# Issue with passing values in JQUERY functions

Tags: javascript, jquery

With some help I have written in JQUERY this:

```
   $('id').clickToggle(addMarker, destroyMarker);
```

where clickToggle is a function which calls addMarker and destroyMarker functions.

This is the clickToggle() function:

```
 $.fn.clickToggle = function(func1, func2) {

        var funcs = [func1, func2];
        this.data('toggleclicked', 0);
        this.click(function() {
            var data = $(this).data();
            var tc = data.toggleclicked;
            $.proxy(funcs[tc], this)();
            data.toggleclicked = (tc + 1) % 2;
        });
        return this;
    };
```

And addMarker() function is

var addMarker = function(){ ....}

I don't have so much xp in JQUERY. What I want to do is to pass a variable inside the addMarker() function. The way my code is written how can I do it?

Comment: OT: `$.proxy(funcs[tc], this)()` -> `funcs[tc].call(this)`

Comment: Which variable do you want to pass to `addMarker`?

Comment: Thanks for the answer! The variable is defined outside the clickToggle() function.  Like this: var id = x;  $('#'+id).clickToggle(addMarker, destroyMarker);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A demo will be very handy here:

[jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ehz59n4a/5/)

HTML

```
<div id="myid">click me</div>
```

Javascript/jquery

```
 $.fn.clickToggle = function(func1, func2) {

        var funcs = [func1, func2];
        this.data('toggleclicked', 0);
        this.click(function() {
            var data = $(this).data();
            var tc = data.toggleclicked;
            $.proxy(funcs[tc], this)();
            data.toggleclicked = (tc + 1) % 2;
        });
        return this;
    };
//lets pass the strings "world" and "foo" to addMarker and destroyMarker 
$('#myid').clickToggle(function(){addMarker("world")}, function(){destroyMarker("foo")});

//pass a variable as a parameter to the functions    
var addMarker = function(x){ alert("addmarker "+x)}
var destroyMarker= function(x){alert("removemarker "+x)}
```

Comment: I had a typo in the code example. It is fixed now :-)

Comment: Thanks but it doesn't seem to work. Nothing is alerted!

Comment: It should work, It is working on my PC (using firefox) so it should work on yours too.

Comment: Yeah. Strange. Instead of the div id I have an image id. It should have the same result.

Comment: What do you mean with image id? The code I posted is the same as in the Jsfiddle except for the comments.

Comment: I use this: $('#'+idImg).clickToggle(function(){addMarker("world")}, function(){destroyMarker("foo")}); Where idImg variable is the id of the img element.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71772/discussion-between-kasper-taeymans-and-dkar).

Answer (score 1):

If you're using a global variable, you can do it like this:

```
var x = 5;

$.fn.clickToggle = function(func1, func2) {

        var funcs = [func1, func2];
        this.data('toggleclicked', 0);
        this.click(function() {
            var data = $(this).data();
            var tc = data.toggleclicked;
            funcs[tc].call(this, x);
            data.toggleclicked = (tc + 1) % 2;
        });
        return this;
    };

$('id').clickToggle(addMarker, destroyMarker);
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2dnhhk5t/)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But how do I pass then the x variable into the addMarker function()?

Comment: @dkar Here: `funcs[tc].call(this, x);`. The `call` allows you to pass parameters, which is what `x` is doing there after the `this` variable.

Comment: Using  global variables is not recommended when not necessary.

Comment: @kasperTaeymans True, but sometimes you can't change your code and just have to make do.

Comment: @dkar Read about the `.call()` function here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call